# How do I change matplotlib's subplot projection of an existing axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, cartopy

I'm trying to construct a simple function that takes a subplot instance (`matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot`) and transforms its projection to another projection, for example, to one of the `cartopy.crs.CRS` projections.

The idea looks something like this

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def make_ax_map(ax, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()):
    # set ax projection to the specified projection
    ...
    # other fancy formatting
    ax2.coastlines()
    ...

# Create a grid of plots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
# the first subplot remains unchanged
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(10))
# the second one gets another projection
make_ax_map(ax2)
```

Of course, I can just use `fig.add_subplot()` function:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax1.plot(np.random.rand(10))

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.coastlines()
```

but I was wondering if there is a proper `matplotlib` method to change a subplot axis projection *after* it was defined. Reading matplotlib API didn't help unfortunately.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

You can't change the projection of an existing axes, the reason is given below. However the solution to your underlying problem is simply to use the `subplot_kw` argument to `plt.subplots()` described in the matplotlib documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots). For example, if you wanted all your subplots to have the `cartopy.crs.PlateCarree` projection you could do

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Create a grid of plots
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()})
```

Regarding the actual question, specifying a projection when you create an axes set determines the axes class you get, which is different for each projection type. For example

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ax1 = plt.subplot(311)
ax2 = plt.subplot(312, projection='polar')
ax3 = plt.subplot(313, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

print(type(ax1))
print(type(ax2))
print(type(ax3))
```

This code will print the following

```
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot'>
<class 'matplotlib.axes._subplots.PolarAxesSubplot'>
<class 'cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxesSubplot'>
```

Notice how each axes is actually an instance of a different class.

Comment: Thanks! And just to confirm, the `projection` keyword determines class for all subplots at once, so there is no way to pass several projections in `subplot_kw`? 

E.g. `projection='polar'` for the first column and `projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()` for the second column of a subplot set created by `plt.subplots(ncols=2)`?

Comment: The keywords in `subplot_kw` are passed to each axes, so I don't think you can do what you describe. The `subplots` function is a convenience wrapper to cater for the basic use case, if you need something more you could write your own wrapper function using `add_subplot` or similar.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with ImageGrid? It would be nice to be able to have the control over map spacing and colorbar placement that ImageGrid allows, but I don't see a way to set the projection for the subplots in the grid.

Comment: Yes, it is possible by using `axes_class` keyword in `ImageGrid` (or `AxesGrid`). There is an [example](http://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/examples/axes_grid_basic.html) in cartopy's gallery.

There was also a PR to cartopy (not accepted though) that can be used to create a custom [`GeoAxesGrid` class](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/835).

Answer (score 10):

Assuming there are multiple axes being used for 2D plotting, like...

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.Figure()
axs = fig.subplots(3, 4) # prepare for multiple subplots
# (some plotting here)
axs[0,0].plot([1,2,3])
```

... one can simply destroy one of them and replace it with a new one having the 3D projection:

```
axs[2,3].remove()
ax = fig.add_subplot(3, 4, 12, projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(...)
```

Just note that unlike rest of Python, the `add_subplot` uses row-column indexing starting **from 1** (not from 0).

EDIT: Changed my typo about indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following function, which removes the axis and generates the axis in the specified projection, similar to [dominecf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63875353/15330539) answer, with the advantage that the specific subplot parameters (row, col, and index) are retrieved automatically.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def update_projection(ax, axi, projection='3d', fig=None):
    if fig is None:
        fig = plt.gcf()
    rows, cols, start, stop = axi.get_subplotspec().get_geometry()
    ax.flat[start].remove()
    ax.flat[start] = fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, start+1, projection=projection)
```

and generate a plot with all available projections

```py
import matplotlib.projections
import numpy as np

# test data
x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 10)

# plot all projections available
projections = matplotlib.projections.get_projection_names()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(projections), figsize=[3.5*len(projections), 4], squeeze=False)
for i, pro_i in enumerate(projections):
    update_projection(ax, ax.flat[i], pro_i)
    ax.flat[i].set_title(pro_i)
    try:
        ax.flat[i].grid(True)
        ax.flat[i].plot(x, x)
    except Exception as a:
        print(pro_i, a)
    
plt.tight_layout(pad=.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

following the answer to this question :

> [In python, how can I inherit and override a method on a class instance, assigning this new version to the same name as the old one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44090563/in-python-how-can-i-inherit-and-override-a-method-on-a-class-instance-assignin)

I found a hack to change the projection of an axe after creating it which seems to work at least in the simple example below, but I have no idea if this solution is the best way

```
from matplotlib.axes import Axes
from matplotlib.projections import register_projection

class CustomAxe(Axes):
    name = 'customaxe'

    def plotko(self, x):
        self.plot(x, 'ko')
        self.set_title('CustomAxe')

register_projection(CustomAxe)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig = plt.figure()

    ## use this syntax to create a customaxe directly
    # ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection="customaxe")

    ## change the projection after creation
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.__class__ = CustomAxe

    ax.plotko(range(10))    
    plt.show()
```

Comment: not working....