# How to use Axes.update() in Matplotlib using Cartopy?

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I need to know how to update the axes of a plot after creation.  I saw in the matplotlib documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.update.html).

I have tried the following code:

```
    ax.update(ax.properties())
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-127-e6624b1841f4>", line 1, in <module>
    ax.update(ax.properties())

  File "C:\Users\cjmar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 974, in update
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]

  File "C:\Users\cjmar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 974, in <listcomp>
    ret = [_update_property(self, k, v) for k, v in props.items()]

  File "C:\Users\cjmar\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 970, in _update_property
    .format(type(self).__name__, k))

AttributeError: 'GeoAxesSubplot' object has no property 'children'
```

and yet examining `ax.properties()` there is indeed a 'children' key there.  Not sure what is going on.  I know that cartopy seems to override the `GeoAxes` class, however, there doesn't seem to be anything overloaded with respect to the update method.

Some example code.  Best to run this in an iPython console so that you can access the `ax` object while the plot is still showing.  May require a `plt.show()` at the bottom.  I use Spyder, which doesn't require this.

```
        import os
        import sys
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        import matplotlib
        import mpl_toolkits
        import numpy as np
        import cartopy

        import cartopy.crs as ccrs
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
        ax.stock_img()

        ny_lon, ny_lat = -75, 43
        delhi_lon, delhi_lat = 77.23, 28.61

        plt.plot([ny_lon, delhi_lon], [ny_lat, delhi_lat],
                  color='blue', linewidth=2, marker='o',
                  transform=ccrs.Geodetic(),
                  )

        plt.plot([ny_lon, delhi_lon], [ny_lat, delhi_lat],
                  color='gray', linestyle='--',
                  transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                  )

        ax.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Polygon([[0,0],[20,0],[20,20],[0,20]],
                                                fill = False,color='g',ls='--',
                                                transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))

        ax.add_patch(matplotlib.patches.Circle([30,30],radius=10,color='g',ls='--',
                                               transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()))

        plt.text(ny_lon - 3, ny_lat - 12, 'New York',
                  horizontalalignment='right',
                  transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

        plt.text(delhi_lon + 3, delhi_lat - 12, 'Delhi',
                  horizontalalignment='left',
                  transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
        # ax.set_extent([-180,180,-90,90])
        ax.set_global()
```

How do I utilize this method properly?

EDIT:
This question is in direct correlation to this other question asked by me.
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60861175/how-to-update-projection-of-geoaxes-using-cartopy)

But the questions are indeed different, as this question is asking how to use the method, and that question is asking how to update an axes projection.

Comment: Can you edit your example to show where `ax.update()` is being called (in the error message is says it's called on line 1, but I don't see in the your example code). Also what's your overall goal that you're trying to achieve by using `ax.update`?

Comment: Hi Jason.  The call to ax.update is done in an iPython console after the plot figure is already being shown (after the code submitted here has already been ran).  Because I have access to the axes object this is perfectly valid.  

To reproduce what I'm doing.  Run this in an iPython console as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: What I meant was what you want the call to `ax.update()` to perform because if you want to make changes to `ax` they'll be reflected in subsequent calls to show the plot. Your error is actually saying that `cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxesSubplot` doesn't have a `.children` attribute meaning that the presence of the key `children` which is returned from your called to `ax.properties()` is what's causing your error.

Comment: Ah, I think I see.  But to answer your initial question, I just want to update the children of the axes.  Because Im trying to update the ax.projection attribute to a different cartopy projection.  Say, PlateCarree -> NorthPolarStereo.  I can change the projection attribute, however, the children of the axes are not updated automatically, hence why I am trying to use the ax.update() call.  But I just don't know how to use it correctly.  And Sorry, dont know how to format code in comment.

Comment: Have you tried calling `plt.show()` after making changes using an `ax` method? Because the methods modify the existing `ax` object in place. Reading your linked question I think that's the behaviour that you're after. Btw you can enclose your text in \` (backticks) to get it to appear as code.

Comment: I think there's some misunderstanding surround 'children' and the use of `ax.update()`. The `ax` object that you've created doesn't have children, all of your lines are modifying the original `ax` object created by `plt.axes(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())`. Under the hood the calls `matplotlib.pyplot.some_method()` are first looking for the current `ax`  or `fig` object and modifying that. Which in common language is considered to be 'updating'.

Comment: That is very possible, however, even normal Matplotlib axes doesn't have `ax.children` property.  I'm just don't know what Matplotlib dox means by props.  Other than a properties dictionary, which is obtained by calling `ax.properties()`.

Comment: Also, a `plt.show()` is not needed after changing the `ax.projection`.  This is because after I edit `ax.projection` I do a `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` which redraws the plot.  This can be verified by doing something like `ax.set_facecolor(.4,.4,.4,.4)`  `ax.figure.canvas.draw()` after the `plt.show()` has already been called.  This will update the facecolor of the axis.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't understand what you want `ax.update()` to do. The `plt` and `ax` methods already modify the `ax` object. `ax.properties()` is a convenient way to get all properties of `ax` but you don't modify that dictionary before passing it to `ax.update()`. Properties refer to the artists used in your plot (line, patch etc.). Their properties are listed [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/tutorials/intermediate/artists.html). There's no concept of an axis having children, you can clone axis to make a new instance but they're always their own instance of the `axes` class.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, It doesn't really matter what I want it to do.  I just need to know how to use it.  Since the documentation is lacking, that is why I came here.  FWIW, the purpose of the project that I'm working on is to make interactive plots.  I want to show data in one projection, and via the toolbar in matplotlib (I have made a tool option to change properties of the axes) change the projection to a different one, update the plot and it now shows the data in the new projection.  I don't know how to copy all of the attributes from one axes to another vice the projection.

Comment: I can get a barebones code set of what I'm trying to do together.. but it will take a while to pull apart my code in a way to do that as it is highly modular.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean to offend you. I'm asking because if you remove the 'children' key from the dictionary returned from `ax.properites()` the expected behaviour would be reapply all of the current settings- which would have no effect on your plot. I assume that the by calling `ax.update()` you wanted _something_ to happen and that's why I'm asking what you want to happen so that I can suggest an approach to get you the results that you want.

Comment: Roger that.  No offense taken (sorry if it came off that way).  I just don't want to divulge the entire process to what I'm doing for purposes I cannot explain.  I will link some code in the future.  Please stay posted.

Comment: Okay, good luck with your project! Feel free to ping me if you have another question!

Comment: Depending on what you want to do this page might be useful for you. [Link to docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/users/event_handling.html)