With Matplotlib, how to create one figure with cartesian and polar coordinates
I want to create a figure with 2 subplots using mosaic and display the same signal in polar and cartesian coordinates with Matplotlib.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0, 30, 0.1)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 1 * t)

fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained")
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(
    [
        ["signal1"],
        ["signal2"],
    ]
)

p1 = ax_dict["signal1"].plot(s)
p2 = ax_dict["signal2"].plot(s)

plt.show()

So I would like to display on the left the figure in cartesian coordinate and on the right in polar. How is it possible ?
Thank you in advance.

Since Matplotlib v3.7, you can pass per_subplot_kw to subplot_mosaic to get different projections for different axes: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.7.0.html#per-subplot-keyword-arguments-in-subplot-mosaic

As @RuthC said, you can pass per_subplot_kw to subplot_mosaic to get different projections for different axes.
fig, axd = plt.subplot_mosaic(
    "AB;CD",
    per_subplot_kw={
        "A": {"projection": "polar"},
        ("C", "D"): {"xscale": "log"},
        "B": {"projection": "3d"},
    },
)


I suggest that you make a reference to the source of your code.

cartesian_polar1.png


cartesian_polar2.png


I'm very indebted to kho's answer. If you appreciate my answer, please consider to appreciate their answer in the first place.
I have tested my answer for a simple subplot_mosaic configuration and a more complex one, and it seems robust across a complicated arrangement.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(0, 10*(2*np.pi), 1001)
f = np.sin(t)*np.cos(t/40) 

def update_projection(axd, label, projection='polar', fig=None):
    # adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485793/2749397
    # by https://stackoverflow.com/users/15330539/kho
    if fig is None: fig = plt.gcf()
    subplotspec = axd[label].get_subplotspec()
    axd[label].remove()
    axd[label] = fig.add_subplot(subplotspec, projection=projection)

fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained", figsize=(10, 7))
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic([["a", "b", "b"],
                              ['c', 'c', 'd']])
update_projection(ax_dict, 'a', 'polar', fig)
update_projection(ax_dict, 'd', 'polar', fig)

ax_dict['a'].plot(t, f); ax_dict['b'].plot(t, f);
ax_dict['c'].plot(t, f); ax_dict['d'].plot(t, f);
plt.savefig('cartesian_polar1.png', dpi=200)

fig = plt.figure(layout="constrained", figsize=(10, 7))
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic([["a", "a", "b", "b", "b"],
                              ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd']])

update_projection(ax_dict, 'a', 'polar', fig)
update_projection(ax_dict, 'd', 'polar', fig)

ax_dict['a'].plot(t, f); ax_dict['b'].plot(t, f);
ax_dict['c'].plot(t, f); ax_dict['d'].plot(t, f);

plt.savefig('cartesian_polar2.png', dpi=200)


Since Matplotlib v3.7, you can pass per_subplot_kw to subplot_mosaic to get different projections for different axes: https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.7.0.html#per-subplot-keyword-arguments-in-subplot-mosaic
